# Pygame text displays wrong fonts

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

I am using pygame to make a game, and I want to display some text, but the font doesn't change to any fonts that I've downloaded. I am using a Mac and the font that I downloaded appears in Font Book. I've used `pygame.font.init`, define the font as `font = pygame.font.SysFont('font name', size)`, and use `font.render(message, False, colour)`.

When defining the font, I tried using both the absolute and relative paths. When I run the program, it displays the text in the default font instead of the font I have downloaded. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pygame.font.Font() instead of SysFont to use downloaded fonts
Using this syntax:

```
font = pygame.font.Font("font name/path", size)
```

use the font.render() function to create a font surface you can display:

```
font.render(yourMessage, True/False, colour)
```